# Blob Storage read efficiency

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

One question about the read efficiency when using Azure Blob Storage. Whehter it's faster to read from multiple small size file (e.g. 5MB) or it's faster to read from a large file (e.g. > 200MB)?

In my current project, I need to persist the stream data in Azure Blob Storage in Avro format and read it afterwards. For example, I can either persist the data every 15min into a single Avro file and that will generate 4*24 = 96 files for one day. Or I can use `AppendBlob` to append all data to one file, which will generate a single Avro file for one day. When reading the data of past few days from the Blob Stroage, which case could be more efficient?

Comment: I don't think this question can be objectively answered. It would depend to a large extent of how would you want to read the data. For example, will you need to read the data for the entire day or will you need to read the data certain time periods (15 minute, 30 minute etc.). Can you please edit your question and provide more details?

Comment: Generally speaking, I would assume that a parallelized system like Spark would perform better with many small files, while a monolithic app may do better with single files.

Comment: @GauravMantri. I want to read the past few days' data from the Blob storage.